# Select and update specific mysql data in single query

Tags: mysql, select, update

I am trying to first select data from a row which contains certain characters. I would then like to update and append new data into another row of those items that were selected. This is my current solution I came up with when trying to combine the two tasks into a single query.

```
SELECT *
FROM `parts`UPDATE  `parts` SET  
`keywords` = CONCAT(`keywords` ,  'Phillips' )
WHERE INSTR(`name`, 'PHI') > 0
```

Comment: And ignore that there is no delimiter between the old keywords and 'Phillips'?

Answer (score 1):

You can make a SELECT as part of an UPDATE statement, but you can't make an UPDATE part of a SELECT statement. However, based on your example you don't need to, instead you can just do the following:

```
UPDATE parts
SET keywords = CONCAT(keywords,'Phillips')
WHERE name LIKE '%Phi%'
```

If you want to retrieve the results after you've updated them just execute the following afterwards:

```
SELECT *
FROM parts
WHERE name LIKE '%Phi%'
```